# How to count rows in a table, where a specific column value is in a list of specified values?

Tags: powerbi, dax

How do I create a DAX measure to count the number of customers in a customer table `dCustomers`, where the `customerType` is either `FR`, `DE` or `GG`?

In SQL, this would be something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(customerId) 
FROM dCustomers 
WHERE customerType IN ('FR', 'DE', 'GG')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the `IN` operator, to write it in a more concise manner:

```
Count (Calculate) = 
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( dCustomers ) ,
    dCustomers[customerType] IN {"FR", "DE", "GG"}
)
```

You can also use `COUNTROWS` directly on the filtered table, this looks to be marginally faster from a bit of testing on a random dataset, but please do benchmarking on a case by case basis:

```
Count (Filter) = 
COUNTROWS ( 
    FILTER (
        dCustomers ,
        dCustomers[customerType] IN {"FR", "DE", "GG"}
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure and use [CALCULATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax) with appropriate filter, like this:

```
Count In List = CALCULATE(COUNT(dCustomers[customerId]),
    dCustomers[customerType] = "FR" ||
    dCustomers[customerType] = "DE" ||
    dCustomers[customerType] = "GG")
```

[image]